# How to get xpath from web page on android mobile phone?

Tags: android, html, xpath

I know how to get XPath of certain element on a webpage via google chrome on my pc but I didn't find a way to do the same on android.

Comment: try `JSOUP` library https://jsoup.org/ , if you provide more information about your issue, we  can help you more

Comment: I'm away from home, on my way somewhere and I want to open webpage on my mobile phone, get xpath for element, paste into IMPORTXML in google sheets. I could use teamviewer + pc for that, but I wonder how can I do that just using my mobile phone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google Chrome remote debugging](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging).

This lets You access the mobile browser on the Chrome Dev tools as if it was the computer.

Comment: No dude. I'm asking how to do it from mobile phone, not from pc. I'm away from home, on my way somewhere and I want to open webpage on my mobile phone, get xpath for element, paste into IMPORTXML in google sheets.

Comment: In that case i would just use view-source: before the url on the address and by reading the HTML create the XPath https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5039/how-do-i-view-source-in-the-android-browser